# C++ error: explicit qualification in declaration

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to work on a tutorial that I wasn't able to finish during class and I'm having a hard time figuring out my errors.  I have never seen an explicit qualification error before so I'm not even sure where to start.  The only resources I can find online for this kind of error has to do when using namespaces and I don't think I am, at least not explicitly  (other than namespace std).

I am sure I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere but these are the errors I'm getting:

```
View.cpp:12:55: error: explicit qualification in declaration of ‘void promptForAnimals(Animal**, int&)’
View.cpp:53:25: error: explicit qualification in declaration of ‘void printDance(Animal*)’
```

and this is my promptForAnimals function:

```
void::promptForAnimals(Animal* barn[], int& numAnimals)
{

  //Animal* barn[MAX_ANIMALS];
  int num;
  string name;

  cout << "How many birds? ";
  cin  >> num; cin.ignore();
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    cout << "Name " << i+1 << ":  ";
    getline(cin, name);
    barn[numAnimals++] = new Bird(name);
  }

  etc
  }

}
```

and my printDanceAnimal is empty, just has:

```
void::printDance(Animal*)
{
}
```

The errors could very well have to do with my header file, so here it is for good measure:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H
#include "Animal.h"
#include "defs.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class View
{
    public:
        View();
        ~View();
        void promptForAnimals(Animal**, int&);
        void printDance(Animal*);

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss class name in these function definitions:

Update:

```
void::promptForAnimals(Animal* barn[], int& numAnimals)
void::printDance(Animal*)
```

To:

```
void View::promptForAnimals(Animal* barn[], int& numAnimals)
void View::printDance(Animal*)
```

Comment: I knew it was a stupid mistake!  Thank you so much!  I've been staring at code for far too long today.

Answer (score 1):

```
void::promptForAnimals(Animal* barn[], int& numAnimals)
```

This is wrong.  Should be:

```
void View::promptForAnimals(Animal* barn[], int& numAnimals)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when you explicitly specify already opened namespace.

```
namespace SomeName {
    int SomeName::someFunc() { return 0; } //error
}
```

I suspect, the empty namespace is the name of the global namespace which is always open, so that is why this kind of error occurs in your case, which is equivalent to that:

```
int ::someFunc() { return 0; } //error again
```